# How can I get a Histogram to display bins as a percentage in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm currently able to generate a histogram with values on the y-axis between 0.0 and 1.0 using hspec "Probability", but I was wondering if there was a way to display it as a percentage instead (this would change nothing but the labelling of the y-axis).

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
Histogram[rawdata, {{0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90,100}}, "Probability", 
          PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
rawdata = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[50, 20], 12000];
bins = {Range[0, 100, 10]};
Histogram[rawdata, bins, "Probability", 
 Ticks ->{First@bins, 
          Table[{.01 i, If[Mod[i , 5] == 0, ToString[i] <> "%", ""]}, {i, 100}]}]
```

[image]

With BarChart you also get full control on Labels, and perhaps it is better in some situations:

```
BarChart[(Length /@ BinLists[rawdata, bins])/Length@rawdata 100, 
  ChartLabels -> bins[[1, 2 ;;]],
  Ticks -> {Automatic,
            Table[{i, If[Mod[i, 5] == 0, ToString[i] <> "%", ""]}, {i, 1, 100}]
           }]
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you are going to use `BinLists[]`, please remember this slippery detail: (from the help)

> In BinLists[data,{xMin,xMax,dx}], elements are placed in bin i when their values satisfy xMin+(i-1) dx <= x < xMin+ i dx.
>
> In the form BinLists[data,{{b1,b2, ...}}], the bi at each end can be -Infinity and +Infinity.